# How to download Xcode manually and install from App Store using downloaded files by redirecting Apple server requests to our local files?

Tags: xcode

I am having problem downloading Xcode from app store. If there is any way to download Xcode manually and install using App Store? Or set App Store cache server to manually downloaded files?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing to download from App Store. You can always copy it from other Macs if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a developer account you can download Xcode (Release and Beta) from Apple Developer website: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: Sometimes your link redirects to store downloads. To always get an actual download link, it may require to go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

Comment: These just link back to the app store. It doesn't answer the question.